# Cannot remove constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have some strange constraints on strange table on my oracle database named `BIN$DHUs7v8fwyvgUAB/AQAHZQ==$0`

I cannot drop these constraints. I am getting the following error:

> ORA-38301: Can not perform DDL/DML over objects in Recycle Bin

Answer (score 10):

These are tables within the [Recycle Bin](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#ADMIN01511) of the database, with other words, those tables have been dropped. To purge them use:

```
purge recyclebin;
```

You can find more about the [PURGE command in the Oracle Database documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9019.htm#SQLRF01803).

Comment: I run Purge recyclebin before posting the question but using sys, however, I should use the schema owner.

Comment: `purge recyclebin;` only purges the current user's recyclebin. If you want to empty the entire recyclebin for the entire database as SYS you have to use `purge dba_recyclebin;`

Answer (score 5):

Oracle [recycle bin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN11679) is a special part of the data dictionary that stores removed objects in a fashion that allows them to later be recovered.

These objects (named `BIN$unique_id$version`, like the object in the question) can be manipulated directly, but instead should be [purged from the recycle bin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9018.htm#SQLRF01803):

```
PURGE INDEX BIN$DHUs7v8fwyvgUAB/AQAHZQ==$0
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to disable the oracle recyclebin, delete the object and then enable it again

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET recyclebin = OFF;
--delete object
ALTER SYSTEM SET recyclebin = on;
```